# Unable to translate in javascript in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7

I am using [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin in a Drupal based website and it is working fine. Problem is I can't translate custom error message from `.po` file. I tried to using `Drupal.t()` function but no luck. When I use this function in `console.log()`, it gives me original message which is written in English but I want it should be translated in other language. Could someone tell me how to translate string from `.po` file to `javascript`. What I did as:

**In Js file:**

```
console.log(Drupal.t('Invalid Email Address.'));
```

**In .po:**

```
msgid "Invalid Email Address."
msgstr "ইমেইলটি সঠিক নয়"
```

Result: `Invalid Email Address.`.

My Drupal version is 7.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check string existence in "Translate" tab of "Translate interface" section (/admin/config/regional/translate/translate)

If string exists, try to reimport your .po file through "Import" tab (/admin/config/regional/translate/import). Perhaps, You will need to use [potx](https://www.drupal.org/project/potx) module to create valid .pot and .po files